# How to put 3 of these tables into the correct spot with CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have 3 tables that I use. I want :

- one on the page left
- one on the page in the center and
- one on the right

All on the same height

The tables can expand and when I use float the expanding goes over the content under it due to the float and I dont want that.

Table code is:

```
<table id="budget">
    <tr>
        <th>Project name</th>
        <th>Deadline</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Project 1</td>
        <td>24/1/2014</td>
        <td><div class="arrow"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><ul>
        <td colspan="5">
         <li> Your total hours: 3:00</li>
          <li>Budget left: &euro;100</li>
                    </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

OR is there maybe a better way to place these tables? I am open for new suggestions.

Comment: Are these tables fixed width?

Comment: No they are not, I can do it if its needed.

Comment: Is the site already built, or are you working from scratch?

Comment: I am seeing this, so what's wrong ? http://jsfiddle.net/4ur8y/1/

Comment: Site is from scratch, just need 3 tables next to each other (left, center and right)

Comment: Use bootstrap  http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: you could just put them in a container div, float one left, one right, and set the centre one as width:33%, margin:0 33%;

Comment: But I would really recommend using bootstrap if you are starting a project.  It's a bit of a learning curve, but its REALLY worth it.  It's also becoming a standard so if someone else comes on the project its better to use a standard with documentation than to just do something your way and have to show each new person how to use it.

Comment: Yeah I see, but I am almost at the end of the project and it seems a bit overkill to learn to work with that for one time.. But thanks anyways!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 3 column layout

HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <div class='left third'>
    <table>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class='centre third'>
    <table>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class='right third'>
    <table>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.third{
  width:33%;
}
div.left{
  float:left;
}
div.right{
  float:right;
}
div.centre{
  float:right;
}
/* This will centre the middle table */
div.centre table{
  width:#####px
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Notes:

1) Width is 33%, not 33.3% to prevent come browsers from wrapping the right column.

2) DO NOT set margins for the columns

3) If possible, use a standard library such as  [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Comment: Just updated and tested in jsFiddle, should work for you

Comment: `+1`, sorry you are no longer `666` rep :)

Answer (score 0):

you can just use margins in css such as:
margin-left:.....
margin-right:....
margin-top:.....
margin-bottom:....

to do it this way you may have to give your td's and th's different id's so you can control them separately

Comment: An answer should not be in the form of a question, this is not jeopardy.  Your answer is actually a comment.

Comment: thanks for letting me know, it will prevent me from doing this in the future

Comment: You should edit the answer, to bring it up to standards

Answer (score 0):

I think you are saying you need three rows/columns in one table whose content is bound to expand.

In header append the stylesheet using

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="q1.css" type="text/css">
```

CODE

```
<table >
<tr >
    <th >Project name</th>
    <th>Deadline</th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
<tr >
    <td>Project 1</td>
    <td>24/1/2014</td>
    <td><div class="scroll">You can use the overflow property when you want to have better control of the layout. The default value is visible.</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="5">
<ul>

     <li> Your total hours: 3:00</li>
      <li>Budget left: &euro;100</li>
                </ul>
    </td>
</tr>

</table>
```

css code

```
table,th,td
{
border : 1px solid black;
border-collapse : collapse;
}
td{
width:10px;
height:10px;
overflow:auto;
}
div.scroll
{
background-color:#00FFFF;
width:100px;
height:100px;
overflow:scroll;
}
```

If the table is overlapping other contents in the page then you could you css

```
clear:both;
```

The clear property specifies which sides of an element other floating elements are not allowed.